# How to deploy via SFTP a website using BitBucket Pipelines

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I want to deploy a repository to server using SFTP Protocol on every Push, I have done it successfully for FTP Protocol,

But the problem is when i have ppk file not a password.I don't have any clue about how to deploy it using bit bucket pipeline only using hostname and ppk file.

is there anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

For those who find this via Google:

There is a area in Settings > SSH keys in you Bitbucket admin that allows you to enter a SSH private/public key pair. Any keypair you enter here will automatically be used to authenticate requests you make via Pipelines. You can only enter one keypair, so you will need to make sure the public key is added to every machine in your deployment pipeline.

Your steps are:

- Generate a new SSH keypair on your computer or use your existing PPK

  - If you use the PPK you already have you will need to use PuttyGen to generate OpenSSH public and private keys from it.
- Add the keypair to Bitbucket via the setting menu
- Ensure the public key is correctly installed on every machine in your pipeline

You should probably also add the host fingerprint of any services you are pushing to to prevent new fingerprint errors. This is below the area where you add SSH keypairs in Bitbucket.

Answer (score -4):

Add password for your user

```
$ sudo passwd USERNAME
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
```

Enable password authentication by editing /etc/ssh/sshd_config: change PasswordAuthentication no to PasswordAuthentication yes

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```